# ReactJS - how to style the parent?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I would like to put style on the "Forms_formline__3DRaL" div (seen below)
This div comes from a component; and it seems like this style is applied to the input , and not its parent div.
How can I, though reactjs, define the style "display: none" for the parent div?

Here is my code:

```
<MyInput
  style={{
    display:
      type == 1
        ? 'none'
        : 'block',
  }}
  id="name"
  type="text"
  label={t('elevation_loss')}
  value="name"
/>
```

Here is the result in my chrome source:

```
<div class="Forms_formline__3DRaL">
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" value="" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: where MyInput is imported from

Comment: [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this

```
import { CSSProperties, FC } from 'react';

export const MyInput: FC<{
    styleOverrides: {
        container: CSSProperties;
    };
    id: string;
    type: string;
    label: string;
}> = ({ styleOverrides }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="Forms_formline__3DRaL" style={styleOverrides.container}>
                ...
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```